# blank page with big loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a query over a database with over 20MM entries, that means im breaking the query into several smaller queries.

The problem is if I try to fetch the 20MM entries the page does not load, and displays a blank screen, with no title and content. However, if I fetch 5MM entries, the page does load correctly, and displays the content:

Here's my code

```
for($n=0; $n<20000000; $n=$n+500000){
    $m=500000;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_likes LIMIT ". $n .",". $m; 
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// craete arrays
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $like[$row['name']]=$like[$row['name']]+1;
    if($like[$row['name']]==375) $likes375 ++; 

}


}

// print the size
echo count($like)."<br>";
echo "375: ".$likes375;
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

after adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` it display this notice: MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because your page will be blank while MySQL is crunching through its index looking for your results. After a while, this will time out (depending on your settings). That is why this doesn't happen on smaller queries.

Comment: actually the query is of the same size, all are of 500.000 rows. However in one case i run 20 times the query, for 10MM rows and  in other i run it 40 times, for 20MM rows

Answer (score 1):

This is due to time limit of execution of php scripts, by default php script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out...

Just use this after `<?php`

```
set_time_limit(0); // 0 means unlimited
```

- but it is not recommended to use it, better improve your logic at the both database and php code logic.

EDIT:

try to set error log for this file specificaly by doing this:

```
ini_set("log_errors" , "1");
ini_set("error_log" , "eorrors.txt");
ini_set("display_errors" , "0");
```

Comment: actually i set the unlimited seconds on each loop

Comment: Yes, if the script is intended to be used interactively you should probably consider using pagination of some kind rather than increasing the time out. If it is just being run as a one-off then there shouldn't be much of a problem with adjusting the time out.

Comment: its intended to use only one time to retrieve the information, not interactively

Comment: Do you have some error log? Maybe try to increese memory limit localy in php script by doing this: ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); * change 64M to whatever you like...

Comment: as you can see in my code I use set_time_limit. I changed it just below <?php and nothing changed

Comment: @DusanRadojevic I seted ini_set('memory_limit', '200M'); and still get blank page...

Comment: @DusanRadojevic i did as you said, but nothing happend. Still no error log for that page

Comment: added: error_reporting(E_ALL); and all i get is Notice: Undefined index: for the line $like[$row['name']]=$like[$row['name']]+1;. Then suddenly the page stop any kind of display